# Spring - Beans not getting injected

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm new to Spring, and I don't entirely understand how to set up bean injection.

I have a class:

```
public class AClass {

    @Autowired
    private Class1 class1;
    @Autowired
    private Class2 class2;
    @Autowired
    private Class3 class3;

    public setClass1(Class1 class1) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public setClass2(Class2 class2) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public setClass3(Class3 class3) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public void doAThing() {
        class1.doSomething();
        class2.doSomething();
        class3.doSomething();
    }
}
```

and I have a test for this class:

```
public class AClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        AClass obj = new AClass();
        obj.doAThing();
    }
}
```

None of the `@Autowired` instances are set after the `AClass` instance is created. Obviously, there is something wrong I'm doing with Spring, and I'd like some tips on what needs to be done to get this working.

(Btw, I am working with a code base at work where Spring configurations are set up in the background, so I don't need to initialize any configs as that is done for me)

Here is my beans xml file:

```xml
<beans ...xml config crap...>

    ...other beans that work for other classes...

    <bean id="class1var" class="apackage.Class1Var" />

    <bean id="class1" class="apackage.Class1">
        <property name="class1var" ref="class1var" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="class2var" class="apackage.Class2Var" factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="class2" class="apackage.Class2">
        <property name="class2var" ref="class2var" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="class3" class="apackage.Class3">
        <property name="class3var" ref="class3var" />
        <!--class3var is defined in another file-->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the bean manually. That's why no bean is being injected by Spring.

Instead, execute your test with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` class by adding `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to your test and signal the configuration using `@ContextConfiguration`. Also, inject your bean into your unit test. Your test should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({
    "/package/where/your/xml/config/files/are/located/spring-config.xml"
    })
public class FooTest {
    //now Spring handles its creation and bean injection
    @Autowired
    AClass aClass;

    public void foo() {
        aClass.doAThing();
        //further code for your test...
    }
}
```

Comment: So you can't create an instance of a class with `@Autowired` fields and have them automatically get injected by Spring?

Comment: Also, with `SpringJUint4ClassRunner`, is a new bean provided for each test? I'd rather not use the same instance for more than one test

Comment: Yes, the point of DI is that you don't have to create instances instead the container takes care of instantiation and life-time handling.